# undefined reference to std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const with boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My application uses boost::asio for network communication.
The issue is that when i launch the application i get :

```
undefined symbol: _ZNKSt9type_infoeqERKS_
```

this after demangling, translates to:

```
std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const
```

After a lot of digging, to know from where in code it is actually being referenced, i added `-Wl,--no-undefined` to my compiler flags, leading to this compile time error:

```
In function `boost::asio::ip::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::ip::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >()':
NetworkService.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail16service_registry11use_serviceINS0_2ip16resolver_serviceINS4_3tcpEEEEERT_v[boost::asio::ip::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::ip::resolver_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >()]+0x83): undefined reference to `std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const'
```

Any suggestions how to find the definition to the function in the error?

Edit:

```
Boost version: 1.55
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2

g++ test.cpp -L$BIN/ -lcommunicationlayer -I/home/tmp/Boost1.55/boost_1_55_0

/bin/libcommunicationlayer.so: undefined reference to `std::type_info::operator==(std::type_info const&) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The test.cpp is:

```
    #include"Service.h"//header to the asio wrapper

    int main()
    {
        netServe Obj;//netServe is a class wrapper over boost-asio
        Obj.setBasicAuthorizationHeader("base64encodedString");
        Obj.setRequestURL("url");
        Obj.send();/*this initiates the resolve,connect,sendrequest,
                   get request sequence of default boost-asio network
                   example available for reference from official boost
                    docs.*/
    }
```

Comment: What compiler are you using and what command are you running to compile and link this program?

Comment: which boost version are you using? please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Are you by any chance providing `no-rtti` compilation flag ?

Comment: @Arunmu  i am not using no-rtti flag.

Comment: @JohnZwinck updated the question with required information.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are using a compiler nearly ten years old?  May I suggest at least GCC 4.9 as a mighty fine replacement?